# Drag and drop between ul with autosave

Tags: php, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, autosave

I'm fairly new to javascripting and php. I need to create a set of separate lists, and have the possibility to drag and drop items between the list. The order in each list doesn't really matter (should be able to adjust with SORT BY).

With the help of some other users, I have the function to drag and drop items, but I also need it to be auto-saved to the database, and I'm not sure where to begin.

[image: Drag&Drop image]

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

EDIT! Rewritten code to PDO. And to be clear: autosave means that upon completion of a drag and drop, I need the scripts to automatically save the new position to the database (ie, a li which is moved from list 1 to list 2 must get updated to position 2 in the database once the drag is complete).

```
//PHP to connect and echo out the three lists
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=server;dbname=db;charset=utf8mb4', 'user', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

// List 1
echo '<ul id="items1" class="items">';
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM dragcolumn WHERE position = 1') as $row) {
echo '<li class="list" id="recordsArray_'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

// List 2
echo '<ul id="items2" class="items">';
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM dragcolumn WHERE position = 2') as $row) {
echo '<li class="list o" id="recordsArray_'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

//List 3
echo '<ul id="items3" class="items">';
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM dragcolumn WHERE position = 3') as $row) {
echo '<li class="list g" id="recordsArray_'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>

//Javascript to move the <li> items
$(function () {
        $("#items1,#items2,#items3,#items4").sortable({
                connectWith: "#items1,#items2,#items3,#items4",
                start: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
            }
    });
    $("#items1,#items2,#items3,#items4").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: mysql functions are deprecated (and removed in php 7) you should learn how to use PDO or mysqli instead

Comment: What means exactly “auto-saved to the database”?

Comment: Auto-save as the javascript should detect that a drag and drop has been done, and save the new position to SQL

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in two ways: 
1. On load of the page i would save start positions of each ul list (li elements) and after drag and drop i would check for current positions of each element and according to that changes would make db manipulations (delete/add) using ajax. 
2. Make db manipulations with the successful drag and drop (when element is dropped) also using ajax.
That is just an idea how to make it, have a look on events and ajax and if you are still struggled with something, i will be happy to help you.

Comment: Thank you! I've thought about ajax (which I've hardly used before). [Katherine Petalio](https://khatzpetalio.wordpress.com/2014/04/03/drag-and-drop-autosave-database/) has a good example on something similar, but not quite what I'm looking for here.

Comment: I have a jquery plugin i was writing for one of my projects, if to modify this plugin it will work well for your task. It is working on touch and mouse events and elements are dragged on a page(not ghost image of them). If you are interested I can share it with you. And even can help to modify it for you needs.

Comment: drag and drop plugin xD

Comment: That sounds awesome! My code above is just an example, and can of course be adjusted. I see the potential to use this functionality in two places of my site, one where I have three columns, and one where there could potentially be 19 or 20 columns. The thing is that there would be several users of the system, so the position must be saved.

Comment: That's great, so you do not need my plugin, just add ajax to you example. I am looking to implement something similar for my future project.  If you have any questions i will try to help. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help so far! I would highly appreciate your help. As I said earlier, I'm new to ajax and javascript, so I'm a bit at a loss as to where to begin. From the example in my earlier comment, you can see the javascript/jquery used (which someone else has written). Also used is [TouchPunch](http://www.pureexample.com/js/lib/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js).

Comment: Ok, sorry i didn't  undetstand you right. I will make an example later on (as i do not have time just now) with use of my plugin. So you will have a better idea of how it works.

Comment: I'm sorry, English isn't my main language, so I might express myself poorly. I'm amazed at the willingness in here to help a newbie out, thank you so much! :-)

Comment: I was working on that task last night and I found it not easy to make it working for multiple columns/lists. I am not an expert as well, but it is like a new challenge for me. I will let you know when make it working. Thank you

Comment: I am slowly moving forward xD. I will continue working on it tonight. So far I have managed to position everything and make li elements draggable. Next step will be work with target elements and after i manage this that we will be able to add ajax to make it working with db. [so far](http://arnuga3.co.uk/Content/draggableUL.html)

Comment: Hi there, I did find a good tutorial and plugin you can download. It is quite similar to the plugin you have already. 1) go to this link, download a plugin with examples [source](http://devheart.org/articles/jquery-customizable-layout-using-drag-and-drop/) 2) build you code based on simple examples. 3) add  TouchPunch file to make it working on touch devices. Do it just now and let me know when you finish, I will help with ajax. Give me a shout if you are struggled with anything. I decided to leave the idea of writing my own plugin as it takes a lot of my time I do not have much just now. :)

Comment: Sorry for late reply! I will have a look at it later today :-) Thanks so much